# powershell output logging to a file

Tags: windows-10, powershell, shell

I am trying to use a command let https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/redirecting-data-with-out---cmdlets?view=powershell-7
as below

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath C:\Users\didja\koera dutata\forum questions\out.txt
    OutFile : The term 'OutFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
    the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:48
    + Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath C:\U ...
    +                                                ~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OutFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath C:\Users\didja\koera dutata\forum questions\out.txt
OutFile : The term 'OutFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:48
+ Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath C:\U ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OutFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath "C:\Users\didja\koera dutata\forum questions\out.txt"
    OutFile : The term 'OutFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
    the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:48
    + Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath "C:\ ...
    +                                                ~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OutFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process |  Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath "C:\Users\didja\koera dutata\forum questions\out.txt"
OutFile : The term 'OutFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:35
+ Get-Process |  Out-Host -Paging | OutFile -FilePath "C:\Users\Danda K ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OutFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process |  OutFile -FilePath "C:\Users\didja\koera dutata\forum questions\out.txt"
OutFile : The term 'OutFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ Get-Process |  OutFile -FilePath "C:\Users\didja\koera duta ...
+                ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OutFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is the mistake in above usage?

Comment: It's `Out-File`

Comment: thanks that was a mistake. this is the commandlet "
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process | Format-List | Out-Host -Paging | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\questions\out.txt"" the file out.txt is blank. What could be the mistake in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out-host` and `out-file` are mutually exclusive. You need to use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do a Tee. Here's what you need:

```
Get-Process | Tee-Object "FilePath" | more
```